# Offline data Sync with Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, xamarin, synchronization, offline

I would like to set up offline data synchronization on Xamarin forms. I did some research and found that mobile application services seems to be an abandoned project. The documentation is obsolete, the nuget package has not been updated for 9 months now and the sample used the old version of the framework. What is the recommended way to implement offline data synchronization on Xamarin forms with .net core backend?

Microsoft Quote :

> Future of Azure Mobile Apps
> Microsoft is committed to fully supporting Azure Mobile Apps, including support for the latest OS release, bug fixes, documentation improvements, and community PR reviews. Please note that the product team is not currently investing in any new feature work for Azure Mobile Apps. We highly appreciate community contributions to all areas of Azure Mobile Apps.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is a UI framework, what does it have to do with synchronization?

Comment: It can use SQLite storage that can be synchronized with a web api and I know there were some sdk and libs for offline data synchronization with MBaaS (old name). So I'm looking for something like that. Thanks.

Comment: What about [Azure Change Tracking](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/azure-sql-change-tracking-data-sync/)? Might get you pointed in the right direction.